# Yandex MapKit iOS : cluster and placemarks

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-mapkit

I am using **Yandex Mapkit iOS SDK** for one of my projects.

It seems that SDK allows adding placemarks is a cluster. Bu I can not add a custom place mark with userData as the same way adding a placemark as a `mapObject`. I want to detect tap action on a marker.

```
// adding markers as mapobjects:
let point = YMKPoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(hit.geom!.lat ?? 0), longitude: Double(hit.geom?.lon ?? 0)))
let placemark: YMKPlacemarkMapObject
self.mapObjects = self.mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects
            
placemark = mapObjects!.addPlacemark(with: point, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker"))
placemark.userData = MarkerUserData(id: Int(hit.id!)!, description: hit.plate!)
placemark.isDraggable = false
placemark.addTapListener(with: self)
            
mapObjects!.addListener(with: self)
```

Adding markers in a cluster, markers can be added to a cluster using only `YMKPoint`. I could not find a way to add a `placemark` object inside a cluster

```
let point = YMKPoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(hit.geom!.lat ?? 0), longitude: Double(hit.geom?.lon ?? 0)))
let placemark: YMKPlacemarkMapObject
        
collection.addPlacemark(with: point, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker"))
// Placemarks won't be displayed until this method is called. It must be also called
// to force clusters update after collection change
collection.clusterPlacemarks(withClusterRadius: 20, minZoom: 5)
```

Comment: FYI: working a lot with clustering and maps, I can recommend [an excellent library](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit) that supports Yandex Mapkit. This library simplified my work and solved the issues related to the definition of tapping and transferring data from the model to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Define a collection with a listener. Fill the array with any points. Go through the array and add each point to the collection. When adding a point to the collection, YMKPlacemarkMapObject is returned, adding user data. And extend your controller delegate method.

And look at the test project with Yandex - https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/blob/master/MapKitDemo/ClusteringViewController.swift

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: YMKMapView!
    var collection: YMKClusterizedPlacemarkCollection?    
    var point: [YMKPoint] = [] // Fill the array with any points

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collection = mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects.addClusterizedPlacemarkCollection(with: self)
        collection?.addTapListener(with: self)

        for point in points {
            let placemark = collection?.addPlacemark(with: point,
                                                           image: UIImage(named: "some_image")!,
                                                           style: YMKIconStyle.init())
            placemark?.userData = "user data"
        }

        collection.clusterPlacemarks(withClusterRadius: 60, minZoom: 15)
    }
}

extension MapViewController: YMKMapObjectTapListener {
    func onMapObjectTap(with mapObject: YMKMapObject, point: YMKPoint) -> Bool {
        guard let userPoint = mapObject as? YMKPlacemarkMapObject else {
            return true
        }

        print(userPoint.userData)
    }
}
```